# Pin Custom Files in Windows 8 Start Screen

Tags: windows-8, start-screen

If I right-click any `.EXE` file, it has the `Pin to Start` option:

[image]

But, if I right-click any file, it doesn't have the `Pin to Start` option:

[image]

Is there any trick/workaround to pin files to the Start Screen?

Comment: Can you pin a .bat file?  If so you could create a .bat file to launch whatever file you really want to have pinned.

Comment: @user168067 No, I didn't see the option on bat files. Very inconvenient indeed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a solution

1. Make a shortcut to the file
2. Navigate to C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs
3. Place your shortcut in the folder
4. Press Windows Key+Q and search the name of your shortcut
5. Right click on the file and select "Pin to Start"

Good Luck!

Comment: Or to `C:\Users\yourloginname\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` folder if you want the shortcut to appear just for your login.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I found a great utility called [Start Screen Pinner](http://winaero.com/download.php?view.36) which lets you pin files, folders, libraries and even special folders to the Start Screen.

Comment: You don't even need a 3rd party utility, see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

For folders, the Pin to start option still exists without installing any additional software

[image: Pin folder to start]

For individual files, you will probably have to use additional software like that recommended by @Root. Full details on [pinning to the start screen](http://www.guidingtech.com/15616/pin-folder-app-file-website-windows-8-start-screen/) are covered in the article linked.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the file you want to pin and select "Create Shortcut"
2. Right click the short-cut and select "Pin to Start"

Related link: [How to pin a control panel item to start?](https://superuser.com/questions/496428/how-to-pin-a-control-panel-item-to-start/496471#496471)

Comment: came here to say this. :)

Comment: this doesn't seem to work anymore (at least, Windows 8 doesn't show me "Pin to start" on shortcuts)

Comment: Shame on Microsoft for not allowing users to pin items of their choice to the Start screen in Windows 8.  This is deliberate on their part, and there is no excuse for it.

Comment: certainly doesn't work with shortcuts in Windows 10