# How do I pin a batch or Command file to the start menu in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

In windows 7 I could pin `batch` or `command files` to my start menu, but I can't figure out how to do this in windows 10.

I can't see windows having a regression like this so I'm assuming that I've done something wrong.

If I can't pin `cmd` files to the start menu what other options do I have for making them easy to click?  Desktop is out as I usually have all my screen real estate covered.

Comment: "In windows 7 I could pin batch or command files to my start menu" No, you couldn't (see marked duplicate), so there's no regression. ;)

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 yes we can, I just did it:)  I'm looking at a cmd file pinned to my windows 7 start menu right now:)

Comment: Ok here's another duplicate that's closer to your exact scenario, and it has the same basic answer, create a shortcut and pin that... [Pin Custom Files in Windows 8 Start Screen](http://superuser.com/questions/495709/pin-custom-files-in-windows-8-start-screen)